Error en query de un campo texto
Cuando intento hacer un query que condicione un campo texto, no me muestra el resultado. el campo hace referencia a un campo código postal. Todo me funcionaba bien pero ahora que estoy cargando códigos postales de otro pais que contiene el formato '07620' no me funciona el query. Solo me funciona cuando en el campo no existen ceros.



Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

¿Qué valor está almacenado en $postal_code?

Gracias, ya lo solucione. No estaba contemplando otra función.
